# Usar compareToIgnoreCase en un if

Tags: java

Tengo que poner un atributo, **madera** o **metal** y he pensado en controlar el setter pero no se por qué el compareToIgnoreCase me da error creo que me falta algo. Creo que va algo después del los ignore case pero no recuerdo.

```
 public void setMaterial(String material) {
        if(this.material.compareToIgnoreCase("madera") || this.material.compareToIgnoreCase("metal") )
        this.material = material;
    }
```

Comment: Que error te da?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu comparación nunca está pasando porque sólo tienes un 0 o un número distinto a 0 ... pero no lo comparas con nada. Tienes que agregar a tu if la comparación en sí.

```
if(material.compareToIgnoreCase("madera") == 0 || material.compareToIgnoreCase("metal") ==0  )
```

Comment: Gracias, al inicializarlo en el constructor lo inicio "" o en madera o metal? ya me surge la duda

Comment: Pues en el constructor supongo que sí debes instanciar la cadena **material** y posteriormente o ahí mismo asignarle un valor ... depende de qué es lo que necesites, pero eso no lo sé con certeza.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos errores en mi parecer:

1. El `compareToIgnoreCase` tienes que igualarlo a un int si quieres que haga la comparacion `compareToIgnoreCase("madera") == 0`
2. En el `if` tienes que eliminar los `this.material` y sustituirlo por `material.co...` ya que lo que buscas es comparar el String que te ha llegado al seter no el valor de material en el objeto

Answer (score 0):

A veces es más productivo hacer un [`toLowerCase/toUpperCase`](https://guru99.es/java-string-tolowercase-methods/) y concatenarlo con [`equals`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/):

```
public void setMaterial(String material) {
    if(this.material.toLowerCase().equals("madera") || this.material.toLowerCase().equals("metal") )
        this.material = material;
}
```